# Continuity of the characteristic function of the subset of algebraic numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be defined as follows:

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x \text{ is algebraic} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

I know that the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ is the subset of algebraic numbers in $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to prove it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this continuous anywhere?  Every open interval contains both algebraic and transcendental numbers.

Comment: you means its not continuous anywhere?

Comment: unless I am misreading, yes!

Comment: Because algebraic and transcendentals are dense?

Comment: That is correct.  The usual "subtle" examples are things like "$g(x)=0$ if $x\notin \mathbb Q$ and $g(x)=\frac 1b$ if $x=\frac ab\in \mathbb Q$.  That one is continuous on irrationals (as the rationals sufficiently near $x$ have very large denominators).

Comment: its Thoamy function?

Comment: Thomae, I think.  Though I just call it a Dirichlet function.  But, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof: let $x_0$ be an algebraic number, so $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists\delta>0$ such that $|f(x_0)-f(y)|<\epsilon \, \forall y$ such that $|x_0-y|<\delta$. Try to take $\epsilon=\frac 1 2$ and use the fact that all the rational numbers are algebraic and the property that exists always a rational number between two real numbers.

Comment: I also want to prove that it is continuous otherwise....Thanks...

Comment: Yes, it's discontinuous anywhere.

Comment: But the given function is Riemann integrable with 0 as its integration..

Comment: It's the same proof but taking $x_0$ trascendent.

Comment: Its not Riemann integrable. It is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: In fact the measure of the set of discontinuity point of $f(x)$ is 1.